# Adding elements to List<List<String>> from an array list

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I want to add COPIES of data to my List but when I use .add, it adds a reference and not a copy. I'll try to explain what I mean.

```
    List<List<String>> formattedTempMatches = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> rowFormattedMatches = new ArrayList<>();
    rowFormattedMatches.add(matchesArray[0]);
    rowFormattedMatches.add(matchesArray[1]);
    rowFormattedMatches.add(matchesArray[2]);
    formattedTempMatches.add(rowFormattedMatches);
    //rowFormattedMatches.clear();
    rowFormattedMatches.add(matchesArray[3]);
    rowFormattedMatches.add(matchesArray[4]);
    rowFormattedMatches.add(matchesArray[5]);
    formattedTempMatches.add(rowFormattedMatches);
```

I've written my code outside of a loop to try to explain myself better. I want to add 3 elements to an ArrayList (of which the elements come from a normal array) then add that ArrayList to a list of lists. When the ArrayList is added to the list, I want to clear it and refill it with 3 more elements and then add it to the next index of the List. The problem is once I clear it, the data is removed from the list. If I don't clear it, the list has 6 elements at each index when there's only supposed to be 3. What should I do?

Apologies for my possibly confusing explanation.

Comment: Try using `formattedTempMatches.add((ArrayList)rowFormattedMatches.clone());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call of `clear()` empties the list. As you are using the same instance for each iteration, this will not work. What you can do instead of clearing the list is create a new instance:

```
List<List<String>> formattedTempMatches = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> rowFormattedMatches = new ArrayList<>();
rowFormattedMatches.add(matchesArray[0]);
rowFormattedMatches.add(matchesArray[1]);
rowFormattedMatches.add(matchesArray[2]);
formattedTempMatches.add(rowFormattedMatches);
rowFormattedMatches = new ArrayList<>(); // new instance of an empty list
rowFormattedMatches.add(matchesArray[3]);
rowFormattedMatches.add(matchesArray[4]);
rowFormattedMatches.add(matchesArray[5]);
formattedTempMatches.add(rowFormattedMatches);
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes the most sense. Dunno why I didn't think of this.